# Why do I have to parse int the size of the vector in a modus operation?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ and I noticed some inconsistency while working with the `size()` method.
Why in the example code below I have 2 different results, one when the size is parsed and other when don't. I'm missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector<int> arr = { 2, 3, 1, -4, -4, 2 };
    cout<< arr.size() << endl; // 6
    cout<< (-1 % arr.size()) << endl; // 3, incorrect without parsing
    cout<< (-1 % 6) << endl; // -1
    cout<< (-1 % (int)arr.size()) << endl; // -1 UPDATE, correct answer onlye when parsed
}
```

## Update:

Yes, I do have a typo in the comment the correct value for the last answer is `-1` again, it's different than the second output `3`.

I actually noticed the issue, while doing a code challenge. The solution in the code  example was parsed, so I was curious "If I don't parse it will I have a different result" and In fact I did. So I open a online editor to test this beahivor. [This is the online code](https://onlinegdb.com/HkwWr9_pI)

Comment: Afaik the % (modulus) of a negative number is found by ignoring the sign, so -1 % 6 = 5.

Comment: What [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) did you read? See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables.

Comment: The last one must be -1, not 3.

Comment: Note that `size()` returns `size_t` which is `unsigned` and that has a huge impact on the result.

Comment: @tadman It does, although I don't understand why `-1 % unsignedSix` == 3.  That's not the result I'd expect if an implicit conversion took place...

Comment: @Benj It's because it doesn't. I tested the code and it gave me 6, 3, -1, -1 for each item there, as expected. The `3` is presumably a transcription error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ : https://ideone.com/9D2IoD

Comment: @tadman My compiler gives 3 for `-1 % unsignedSix`

Comment: @Benj Which compiler? Which architecture?

Comment: @Bathsheba - Right, `4294967295 % 6` does indeed give 3.

Comment: `size_t` might be 64-bit (but 3 comes in both cases this time, unlike in the question I've linked

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in your question: the last `cout` outputs `-1` unless your compiler is defective (unlikely), or you have a pre C++11 compiler with a curiously documented behaviour of `%` for a negative first argument (extremely unlikely).

In the case of `-1 % arr.size()`, `-1` is converted to an `unsigned` type since `arr.size()` is required by the C++ standard to return an `unsigned` type.

`-1 % 6` is `-1` from and including C++11. Prior to that, the value was implementation defined.

You'd find it instructive to inspect the output of

```
std::cout << (-1 % 6U) << std::endl;
```

which, in your case, will be 3.

Comment: Running the code as-is gives 6, 3, -1, -1 for me on `clang`.

Comment: @tadman: Thank the Lord for that!

Comment: Yeah, looking at it I thought it was odd that being signed vs. unsigned would not affect the answer, but it did.

Comment: Yes, I do have a typo I update my question thanks for the observation. @Bathsheba